# Finding last coefficient of a multivariate polynomial in $GF(2)$ in polynomial time

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, multivariate-polynomial

*This problem was simplified by Alex Ravsky (thanks!). For the original problem see below.*

**Simplified Problem**

With $f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$ a polynomial over $GF(2)$, find the value of the coefficient of the term that contains all variables $k_i$ (in other words the coefficient $a\in GF(2)$ of the term $a\prod_{i=1}^n k_i$). There is only one such term in the simplified polynomial because $\forall x\in GF(2),n\in \mathbb{N}: x^n=x$. However, $f$ is too long to be multiplied out completely in practice and can only be represented as a tree of nested sums and products (in which most leaves are present at multiple points throughout the tree). Even though this simpler than the original problem, finding that coefficient algorithmically in polynomial time is still proving challenging and I would appreciate all the help I can get! :D

---

**Original Problem**

Essentially I have a nested sum in the form
$$\sum_{k_1=0}^1 \sum_{k_2=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1 f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$$
where $f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$ is a multivariate polynomial over $GF(2)$ which can only be represented as a tree of nested sums and products because multiplying it out would lead to on average $2^{n-1}$ terms (the number of possible terms is $2^n$ because in $GF(2)$ every $k_i=k_i^j$ for $j\in\mathbb{N}$ and the number of possible variable combinations $1;k_1;k_2;k_2k_1;k_3;k_3k_1;k_3k_2;k_3k_2k_1;\ldots$ is $2^n$).

Finding the value of $f$ for a specific set of $k_i$ is trivial, but the exponential time complexity of doing this $2^n$ times (the total number of elements in our nested sum) is a bit of a buzzkill. I'm a patient guy but not enough so to wait longer than the age of the universe, so I'd much prefer to do this in polynomial time :)

So far, I've tried reordering the sum to
$$\sum_{k_1=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_{i-1}=0}^1 \sum_{k_{i+1}=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1 \sum_{k_i=0}^1 f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$$
for some specific $i$ and finding $a,b \in GF(2)$ such that $f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)=k_ia+b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are each polynomials independent of $k_i$ represented as a tree similar to $f$; this is trivial to do for a single $k_i$) because in $GF(2)$ I can then do
$$\sum_{k_i=0}^1 f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)=\sum_{k_i=0}^1 (k_ia+b)=0a+b+1a+b=a+b+b=a$$
which means that
$$\sum_{k_1=0}^1 \sum_{k_2=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1 f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)=\sum_{k_1=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_{i-1}=0}^1 \sum_{k_{i+1}=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1 a$$
which in turn means that I've halved the number of elements of the nested sum. However, the complexity of $a$ is usually higher than the complexity of $f$, because when isolating $k_i$ from $f$, the following happens each time a product is encountered in the tree representing $f$, of which at least two factors are dependent on $k_i$:

Let $k_ia_1+b_1$ and $k_ia_2+b_2$ be two such factors from which $k_i$ is to be isolated such that we obtain an $a_0$ and $b_0$ with $k_ia_0+b_0=(k_ia_1+b_1)(k_ia_2+b_2)$. Finding
$$(k_ia_1+b_1)(k_ia_2+b_2)=k_i^2a_1a_2+k_ia_1b_2+k_ia_2b_1+b_1b_2=k_ia_1a_2+k_ia_1b_2+k_ia_2b_1+b_1b_2=k_i(a_1a_2+a_1b_2+a_2b_1)+b_1b_2$$
is simple, however, even if this were the closest such product to the base of the tree, which would mean that $b_0$ falls away due to the mechanism described above, and even if I rewrite $a_0=a_1a_2+a_1b_2+a_2b_1=(a_1+b_1)(a_2+b_2)+b_1b_2$ to minimize the number of products added to the tree, I've just added at least two products to the tree, each of which will add at least two more products to the tree when I isolate the next $k_j$ because $a_1,a_2,b_1,$ and $b_2$ are almost certain to be dependent on $k_j$. Therefore, we're back to the exponential time complexity. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find a way to get around this problem.

Because we're in $GF(2)$, of course, this problem stays identical if all of the equalities above are replaced with congruences modulo $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. I don't actually know if it's easier to think of the problem in such terms, however.

Thank you so much for making it this far through my lengthy question! I very much look forward to reading your ideas :)

Comment: This seems very hard to do treating the polynomial as a black box. Can you say anything about what the polynomial is?

Comment: The polynomial itself varies by quite a bit and unfortunately the only given is that it is a finite tree of sums and products, eg f=a\*b; a=c+d+e; b=d\*g\*h; c=k_1+g+j and so on. I do know that most of these "intermediate variables" occur many times, such that even just writing out f completely by recursively substituting all the "intermediate variables" with their respective values, without multiplying out the resulting expression, is impossible in practice because the resulting expression is simply too long.

Comment: The problem is that *any* of the $2^{2^n}$ $n$-variable functions over $GF(2)$ can be expressed as a finite tree of sums and products. If we don't know anything else about it, then evaluating $f$ even $2^n-1$ times would give us no information about the sum.

Comment: This is actually exactly the point. We have any function for which we only have this polynomial representation, and we want to find the sum of all of its images for every combination of its inputs. And that sum is exactly the same as the one coefficient of the term dependent on all of the variables in the input, as Alex Ravsky pointed out in a since deleted answer. We also have the ability to compute individual images of the function, but computing every single image and calculating the sum is too computationally intensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $f$, put $S(f)=\sum_{k_1=0}^1 \sum_{k_2=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1 f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)$. As I understood, the complexity of an algorithm calculating $S(f)$ depends on the representation of $f$. Indeed, put $\Bbb F=GF(2)$ and $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$. Since $x^j=x$ for each $x\in\Bbb F$ and $j\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists a polynomial $\bar f\in\Bbb F[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that $\bar f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ for each $x_1,\dots,x_n\in\Bbb F$ and $\bar f$ has degree at most $1$ with respect to each variable. Then $\bar f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=\sum_{A\subset [n]} a_A\prod_{i\in A} x_i$, where $a_A$’s belong to $\Bbb F$ and, for the convenience,
$\prod_{i\in \varnothing} x_i=1$. Remark that $\prod_{i\in A} k_i$ equals $1$, if $k_i=1$ for each $i\in A$, and equals $0$, otherwise. Then
$$S(f)=\sum_{k_1=0}^1 \sum_{k_2=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1 f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)=$$
$$\sum_{k_1=0}^1 \sum_{k_2=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1 \bar f(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n)=$$
$$\sum_{k_1=0}^1 \sum_{k_2=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1 \sum_{A\subset [n]} a_A\prod_{i\in A} k_i=$$
$$\sum_{A\subset [n]} \sum_{k_1=0}^1 \sum_{k_2=0}^1 \ldots \sum_{k_n=0}^1  a_A\prod_{i\in A} k_i=$$
$$\sum_{A\subset [n]}2^{n-|A|} a_A=
a_{[n]}.$$

That is if $f$ is represented as a sum of monomials then we can easily calculate $S(f)$.

On the other hand, if $f$ is represented as a tree of nested sums and products then, as I understood, the calculation of $S(f)$ can be hard. Namely, elements of $\Bbb F$ can be considered as Boolean constants. Using equalities $x \wedge y=xy$ and $x\vee y=x+y-xy$, and $\neg x=1-x$ we can consider Boolean formulas depending on $x_1,\dots, x_n$ as as polynomials from $\Bbb F[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and vise versa. Then $S(f)=1$ iff the Boolean formula corresponding to $f$ has an odd number of variable assignments making it true.

Ryan Williams noted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21016/how-hard-is-it-to-solve-sat-if-the-promise-is-that-it-has-an-odd-number-of-solut/21026#21026) that “the problem "Parity-SAT" (often written as $\oplus SAT$ in the literature) is the problem of determining whether or not a given Boolean formula has an odd number of assignments. It is well-studied, and is complete for the class $\oplus P$ which contains all languages of the form {$x ~|~ $ there are an odd number of accepting computation paths in $N(x)$}, where $N$ is a nondeterministic polynomial time machine”. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_P) about the complexity class $\oplus P$. In particular, it contains the [graph isomorphism problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem), which is not known to be solvable in polynomial time nor to be NP-complete. On the other hard, Parity SAT is NP-hard under randomized reductions, see [VV, p.92].

*References*

[VV] L.G. Valiant, V.V. Vazirani, *[NP is as easy as detecting unique solutions](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos528/handouts/NP_is_as.pdf)*, Theoretical Computer Science **47** (1986) 85–93.

Comment: Thank you so much for the really helpful answer :D and especially for pointing out that the entire expression is equal to $a_{[n]}$. I wasn't able to follow the $a_{[n]}=f(1,1,\ldots,1)$ however. Isn't $f(1,1,\ldots,1)=\sum_{A\subset[n]}a_A$? And wouldn't then a counterexample be $f(k_1)=k_1+1$ because $\sum_{k_1=0}^1 f(k_1)=0+1+1+1=1 \ne f(1)=1+1=0$?

Comment: @Kenny I updated the answer.